# coloring button in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I try coloring two button .. button X and button Y .. when I click in button X so coloring blue and when I click in button Y so coloring red ...

code ts:

```
    public colorX:boolean =false;
        public colorY:boolean =false;

     public countX(colorX)
        {
            if (colorX === false) { colorX=true;}
        }

        public countY(colorY)
        {
            if (colorY === false) { colorY=true;}
        }
```

code html:

```
          <ion-row no-padding>
          <ion-col>
              <span (click)="colorX=!colorX; countX(colorX)">
                <i class='fas fa-thumbs-up' [ngStyle]="{'color': colorX ===true ? 'blue' : 'black'}" ></i>
                12 
                </span>
              <span (click)="colorY=!colorY; countY(colorY)">
                <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down" [ngStyle]="{'color': colorY ===true ? 'red' : 'black'}"></i>
                4 
              </span> 
              <span>
                <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                12 
              </span>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-card> 
        </ion-col>


          <ion-row no-padding>
          <ion-col>
              <span (click)="colorX=!colorX; countlike(colorX)">
                <i class='fas fa-thumbs-up' [ngStyle]="{'color': colorX ===true ? 'blue' : 'black'}" ></i>
                12 
                </span>
              <span (click)="colorY=!colorY; countY(colorY)">
                <i class="fas fa-thumbs-down" [ngStyle]="{'color': colorY ===true ? 'red' : 'black'}"></i>
                4 
              </span> 
              <span>
                <i class="fas fa-comment"></i>
                12 
              </span>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-card> 
        </ion-col>
```

now when I click on first button X so coloring button X but also second button X is coloring .. and when  I click on first button X so coloring first button X but also second button Y is coloring ...

how coding when I click on first button X just first button X coloring and second button X not coloring also for button Y when I click on first button Y just button first button Y is coloring and second button Y not coloring

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the function in your controller at all.

```
(click)="colorX=!colorX;"
(click)="colorY=!colorY;"
```

You said you want them colored separately, so you have no option but to give them separate variables. Create another variable in your controller.

```
(click)="colorXTwo=!colorXTwo;"
(click)="colorYTwo=!colorYTwo;"
```

dont call a function after that

Comment: but also error with your modification because when colorX is false so all span content coloX=false so all span is coloring :(

Comment: Oh so you're trying to separate the button groups? Then just create two more variables.